# How to set a hdd partition for storage in windows/ubuntu dual boot?

Tags: partitioning, windows, storage

I have installed a dual boot with windows and ubuntu on my laptop but the problem is that the ubuntu only has 60 gb of storage from my ssd drive. Is there a way I can partition my hdd drive through windows so that I can set the empty partition as storage in ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both Windows and Ubuntu are working ok you need to do the following;

1. Backup your data
2. Shrink your Windows partition from Windows using the Windows disk management
3. Expand your Ubuntu partition using the Gparted application in Ubuntu

Ask if you need more details but there are plenty of answered questions on here and videos on YouTube that will help